# Cannot preview PDF publicly shared file

Tags: pdf, files, preview

I have a couple of PDF files that have public links that are no longer showing a file preview.  Any thoughts why or what I can do to fix this problem.  I have refreshed the preview link & also re-uploaded the files.  They consistently say no file preview available.  I can download them.

Comment: Are those salesforce files linked to a record, or in document or inside the Library

Comment: These are files that are simply uploaded as files and shared with a public link.  I just did some testing.  Any of my PDFs that are greater than 10 pages do not show a file preview.  This is definitely a change.  I am guessing since Winter '19??  Any thoughts on working around this limitation?  I can put the files as static resources but am hoping for a different solution.

Comment: I should clarify that the preview is not showing when I try to view the file view the public link.  I can see the preview when looking at it via internal Salesforce.